# how to Integrate spring boot in project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Maybe my question is a little base, but i seldom use spring boot. Here i create a such project and have some questions below:

1. why i need to use add spring-boot-starter-parent as parent? what's the usage of `<relativepath />` usage in it?
2. I have already add spring-boot-starter-web in pom.xml, everything is ok but my **.java file appears `FilterRegistrationBean` not found**, it's a compile error ! why? Here i can see such jar file dependencies in `project structure`(Here i'm using Idea 2016)

Here is my project pom.xml file snippet, Hope some one can give me a hand, thanks:

```
<groupId>org.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.14.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

### update:

after almost half an hour discovering, i found it's a **Idea bug**. maybe such class can not find under classpath before, but after **changing the right version dependencies and re-organize import(just remove such error import and auto-import new one)**, then application can start normally. So strange !  maybe i should report to JetBrain. 
finally, no matter what, thanks every body ever give me hints, I will give upvote for you ~.~.

Here is my final `pom.xml`, if you want to check your dependencies which already download in Idea, you can see `*.iml` file(there are many type='library' entry):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.14.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: adding something as parent means it will inherit dependencies from parent pom, you could have very well added it as `<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>`

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: Are you creating a new project? Or tryingto use boot in an existing project?

Comment: @bestwishes so i can not add it as parent directly? but in such way i can still see some jar dependencies in classpath

Comment: @Can'tTell a new project

Comment: How did you create your project? Did you copy paste the content of the pom file?

Comment: @Christian just `FilterRegistrationBean ` compile error, which locate in spring-boot-1.3.5-release.jar file, but such file can not find in classpath

Comment: @Can'tTell I have add all dependencies above, no more dependencies. and I hava set up Idea `auto-import`. so if you mean such dependencies have not download from remote, maybe not

Answer (score 1):

May not fix the actual issue, but you don't need to include a version on all the starters in your pom.xml.

You've specified a version for spring-boot-starter-parent, so that will take care of using the correct version for all the other starters in your dependencies.

Comment: so if i add a spring-boot-starter-parent as parent, then i don't need to specify other dependencies starters version because there are already specified it in parent?

Comment: Correct - let Spring Boot take care of the version management for the starter dependencies. You can override the version numbers, but it's not recommended: https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot